# TypeError when adding row to Google spreadsheet (using Python)

Tags: python, gdata, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to simply insert a row into a spreadsheet using this:

```
# this is how I create the spreadsheet document
doc_client = getDocAPIService(user_id) # a separate function handles oauth and returns the doc client
doc = gdata.docs.data.Resource(type='spreadsheet', title='test')
doc = doc_client.CreateResource(doc)
spreadsheet_key = doc.GetId().split("%3A")[1]

# I then try to manipulate the spreadsheet
fields = {'test': 'test'}
sheet_client = getSpreadhseetAPIService() # again, a separate function handles oauth
entry = sheet_client.InsertRow(fields, spreadsheet_key, wksht_id='od6')
```

I can add worksheets fine and get feeds etc., but adding a row would yield this error:

```
TypeError: unbound method _AddMembersToElementTree() must be called with ExtensionContainer instance as first argument (got SpreadsheetsList instance instead)
```

These are the helper functions to get the clients and handle oauth, in case important:

```
def getDocAPIService(username):
    two_legged_oauth_token = gdata.gauth.TwoLeggedOAuthHmacToken(
        config.OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, config.OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, username)
    client_docs = MyDocsClient(source="myapp")
    client_docs.auth_token = two_legged_oauth_token
    client_docs.ssl = True
    client_docs.http_client.debug = True
    client_docs.http_client.deadline = 30
    return client_docs

def getSpreadhseetAPIService():
    gdocs = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService(source="myapp")
    gdocs.SetOAuthInputParameters(gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1, config.OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,
                                  consumer_secret=config.OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET)
    gdata.alt.appengine.run_on_appengine(gdocs)
    return gdocs
```

This is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path_to_project/tornado/web.py", line 954, in _execute
    getattr(self, self.request.method.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path_to_project/tornado/web.py", line 1667, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path_to_project/script.py", line 999, in get
    doc = generateSpreadsheetFromTemplate(template, current_user.email())
  File "/path_to_project/utils.py", line 183, in generateSpreadsheetFromTemplate
    entry = sheet_client.InsertRow(fields, spreadsheet_key, wksht_id='od6')
  File "/path_to_project/gdata/spreadsheet/service.py", line 339, in InsertRow
    converter=gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsListFromString)
  File "/path_to_project/gdata/service.py", line 1236, in Post
    media_source=media_source, converter=converter)
  File "/path_to_project/gdata/service.py", line 1322, in PostOrPut
    headers=extra_headers, url_params=url_params)
  File "/path_to_project/atom/__init__.py", line 93, in optional_warn_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path_to_project/gdata/atom/service.py", line 176, in request
    content_length = CalculateDataLength(data)
  File "/path_to_project/gdata/atom/service.py", line 736, in CalculateDataLength
    return len(str(data))
  File "/path_to_project/gdata/atom/__init__.py", line 377, in __str__
    return self.ToString()
  File "/path_to_project/gdata/atom/__init__.py", line 374, in ToString
    return ElementTree.tostring(self._ToElementTree(), encoding=string_encoding)
  File "/path_to_project/gdata/atom/__init__.py", line 369, in _ToElementTree
    self._AddMembersToElementTree(new_tree)
  File "/path_to_project/gdata/spreadsheet/__init__.py", line 372, in _AddMembersToElementTree
    atom.ExtensionContainer._AddMembersToElementTree(self, tree)
TypeError: unbound method _AddMembersToElementTree() must be called with ExtensionContainer instance as first argument (got SpreadsheetsList instance instead)
```

Any idea why is this so?

Thanks,

Arbie